# How can I show values from two tables with one SELECT command in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. First table has food items with prices on it. The other table has orders of foods on it. Both tables have the same named food items. What I would like to do is, have the price show as an extra column behind the particular food item in one table.

I don't even know how to search for this, I tried and failed miserably. So now I am turning to people who are most likely better at SQL.

Hope someone understands my problem and is able to help me.

Comment: Give us the structure of your tables and some data

Comment: you should start with joins... and few select statements... If you need query show the table structure

Comment: use joins on two tables on food items. get the necessary information in select list...provide sample tables with data and required output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a join:

```
select orders.*, prices.price
from orders
join prices on prices.foodName = orders.foodName
```

Comment: Thanks everybody, but this worked excellent. Thank you Bohemian. You just helped me do my homework.